# windows.onunload not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, onunload

I am currently doing a project using an eyetracking tool where when the student clicks on an exercise, it will start recording the eye gaze patterns and when the student navigates away from the exercise page, it will stop recording the eye gaze patterns.

I am using windows.onunload but it seems to not work on my block of codes.

variable connection is the websocket.

```
window.onunload = function () {
        connection.send('closing connection');
        connection.onclose = function(){
            connection.send('<SET ID="ENABLE_SEND_DATA" STATE="0" /> ');
            console.log("Connection closed");
        }; 
    };
```

This codes are supposed to close the connection but it didn't. It was successful once but it didn't work properly after. Anyone has an answer for this?

Comment: Never trust an unload to occur. Ensure your state gets synced whenever users interact with your/site app and assume they just close the entire browser using `kill -9` or "task manager" -> "end process", at any moment. Conversely, make the server timeout at a sensible interval (i.e. 30 seconds after the last user interaction with the page, not "with the database" or the like. And not 10 minutes or something similar of "no activity at all")

Comment: What is the `connection` variable?

Comment: you can't (reliably) do anything asynchronous on unload - use [sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) instead - though, I'm not sure what `connection` is, so it may not be easy - as a side note, there are some techniques discussed in the documentation I linked to that may work for you

Comment: @Finesse the connection variable is a websocket